# mod_fcgid: can't run C:/Program

Tags: apache

I have compiled an fastcgid example program along-with libfcgid files using visual studio 10 compiler. The exe file works correctly. But when I try to open the exe file using a browser through apache server, after much delay the following is displayed in the browser.

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

The apache log file contains the following errors:

```
[error] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : mod_fcgid: can't run C:/Program
[warn] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : mod_fcgid: spawn process C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/test/fcgitest.exe error
[warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/test/fcgitest.exe
```

I have noticed the error occurs when I include the following line in httpd.conf

SetHandler fcgid-script

Can anyone help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I installed apache in path 'C:program files'. It has a space character in path. It was the reason for this error. So I uninstalled apache and re-installed in c drive so that the installation folder is C:apache2.2. This solved the error.